# How to put image as letterbox in video

Tags: azure-media-services

When I converted my video using Azure Media Services to format 9x16 letterboxes appeared in the top and the bottom. I used `stretchMode: "AutoFit"` so letterbox is actually a normal effect here.

> Pad the output (with either letterbox or pillar box) to honor the output resolution, while ensuring that the active video region in the output has the same aspect ratio as the input. For example, if the input is 1920x1080 and the encoding preset asks for 1280x1280, then the output will be at 1280x1280, which contains an inner rectangle of 1280x720 at aspect ratio of 16:9, and pillar box regions 280 pixels wide at the left and right.

However I wonder if this is possible to put an image there instead of having them just black.

My video looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we do not currently support placing background images during a stretch or letterboxing operation. If possible, and you do not have a ton of these videos to process, I recommend running them through a free compositing application like BlackMagic's Davinci Resolve to get the intended effect and then uploading the final output for streaming.